# Integer min/max value peculiar overflow behavior

Tags: java, scala, jvm

Why is `Integer.MIN_VALUE * 2` equal to `0`?

And `Integer.MAX_VALUE * 2` equal to `-2`?

Let me explain myself better:

I know it overflows, but why does it get these specific results?

Comment: Integer overflow.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Integer.MIN_VALUE= -2147483648`. Have a look at bit calculation of `2 * -2147483648`

```
   Integer.MIN_VALUE*2  = Integer.MIN_VALUE+Integer.MIN_VALUE


         -2147483648=  10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ->32 bit
                      +10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
  _________________________________________________________________
     2* -2147483648= 1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 Result is 0
                     |
                    This bit will be omitted due to limitation of 32 bit
```

`Integer.MAX_VALUE=2147483647`, Have a look at bit calculation of `2 * 2147483647`

```
   Integer.MAX_VALUE*2  = Integer.MAX_VALUE+Integer.MAX_VALUE


          2147483647=  01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 ->32 bit
                      +01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
  _________________________________________________________________
       2* 2147483647=  11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110 Result is -2
```

Comment: what about Max value and I do not think that Integer.MIN_VALUE*2   will be calculated as Integer.MIN_VALUE+Integer.MIN_VALUE

Comment: @dbw: You might treat the multiplication by 2 in both cases as a "bit shift left by 1", but the result will obviously be the same!

Comment: @Masud I disagree the `multiplication` is the combination of `summation`, just look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm **Shift and End** section it is written " Most currently available microprocessors implement this or other similar algorithms (such as Booth encoding) for various integer and floating-point sizes in hardware multipliers or in microcode"

Comment: @dbw, But result will be same.

Answer (score 3):

```
scala> println(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
2147483647

scala> println(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
-2147483648
```

So, `Integer.MIN_VALUE` = - (`Integer.MAX_VALUE` + 1)

So if `MIN_VALUE + MIN_VALUE = 0` then `MAX_VALUE + MAX_VALUE = 0 - 1 - 1 = -2`

Answer (score 1):

In a computer system, values are expressed in the complementary code keying
Positive is the complement of its own
Complement is equal to the absolute value of the negative of the original code you negated, and the whole number 1 for the number of